# How to solve given ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$$\cos x\frac{dy}{dx}+y\sin x=\frac{\cos x}{e^x}$$

I have tried methods such as Integral multiplier , exact differential.The Integral of the solution part is difficult. $\displaystyle \int \sec x \frac{dx}{e^x}$

Can I solve it with another solution method?

Comment: Looks like you made an algebra error, when I divide through by $\cos(x)$ I get $y'+\tan(x) y = e^{-x}$.

Comment: Yes, but if you continue you need to solve $\int e^{-x}\sec^{2}(x)dx$.

Comment: Nothing you can do about it. And no method will change that...The integral is hard to evaluate. You can keep the solution with the integral.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Multiply both sides of ODE by $\sec^{2}(x)$, so you obtain a exact equation and if considerer the ODE as a linear equation, so you can take $\mu(x)=\sec(x)$ as integrate factor.

Comment: I've created a exact equation but in the last part ; $\int((ysinx/cos^2x)-(secx/e^x))dx+\int(dy/cosx)=0$. I need an integral to keep going.

Comment: You can express the solution as $\sec(x)y(x)=\int e^{-x}\sec^{2}dx$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos x\frac{dy}{dx}+y\sin x=\frac{\cos x}{e^x}$$
$$\left (\frac{y}{\cos x}\right )'=\frac 1{\cos x e^x}$$
There is nothing you can do about the integral on RHS. The integral is hard to calculate. The mehod used to integrate the DE won't chane anything to this problem.Keep the integral in the solution.
$$y(x)=C \cos x +\cos x\int \frac {dx}{\cos x e^x}$$